# Ethereum: invoking contract function with bytes32 array

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, arrays, bytes

i have the following contract function

```
    function voteForAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32[] answerKeys)
     returns (bool success)
{
    // is the sender allowed to do this?
    if (voters[msg.sender].enabled == false) {
        throw;
    }
    // TODO: check for question existence;
    if (questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] == true) {
        throw;
    }
    questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;
    for (uint i; i <= answerKeys.length; i++) {
        questions[questionKey].answers[answerKeys[i]].voteCount += 1;
        VoterVotedFor(msg.sender, questionKey, answerKeys[i]);
    }
}
```

How can i invoke the contract function?

[image]

currently i get the following Mist-Message

[image]

What do i wrong?

Thanks
Thomas

**UPDATE**

i adapted my contract so that i do not use any more an array in my function VoteForAnswer; i still get an error:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract Roadshow is owned {

    bytes32 public text;  // shortname (up to 32 bytes)
    uint public start; // datetime when roadshow starts
    uint public end;   // datetime when roadshow ends
    mapping(address => Voter) public voters;

    struct Voter {
        bool enabled;  // if true, that person is currently allowed to vote
    }

    struct Answer
    {
        bytes32 text;
        uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
        // add more non-key fields as needed
    }

    struct Question
    {
        bytes32 text;
        mapping(bytes32 => Answer) answers; // random access by question key and answer key
        bytes32[] answerList; // list of answer keys so we can look them up
        // add more non-key fields as needed
        mapping(address => bool) alreadyVoted;
      }

    mapping(bytes32 => Question) questions; // random access by question key
    bytes32[] questionList; // list of question keys so we can enumerate them

    function Roadshow(bytes32 _name) {
        text = _name;
        start = now;
        voters[msg.sender].enabled = true;
    }

    function addQuestion(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 text)
        onlyOwner
        returns(bool success)
    {
        // not checking for duplicates
        questions[questionKey].text = text;
        questionList.push(questionKey);
        return true;
    }

    function getQuestion(bytes32 questionKey)
        public
        constant
        returns(bytes32 wording, uint answerCount)
    {
        return(
            questions[questionKey].text,
            questions[questionKey].answerList.length);
    }

    function addAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey, bytes32 answerText)
        onlyOwner
        returns(bool success)
    {
        questions[questionKey].answerList.push(answerKey);
        questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].text = answerText;
        // answer vote will init to 0 without our help
        // questionStructs[questionKey].answerStructs[answerKey].voteCount = 0;

        return true;
    }

    function getQuestionAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey)
        public
        constant
        returns(bytes32 answerText, uint answerVoteCount)
    {
        return(
            questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].text,
            questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].voteCount);
    }

    function getQuestionAnswerText(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey)
        public
        constant
        returns(bytes32 answerText)
    {
        answerText = questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].text;

        return answerText;
    }

    function getQuestionAnswerCount(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey)
        public
        constant
        returns(uint answerCount)
    {
        answerCount = questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].voteCount;

        return answerCount;
    }

    function getQuestionCount()
        public
        constant
        returns(uint questionCount)
    {
        return questionList.length;
    }

    function getQuestionAtIndex(uint row)
        public
        constant
        returns(bytes32 questionkey)
    {
        return questionList[row];
    }

    function getQuestionAnswerCount(bytes32 questionKey)
        public
        constant
        returns(uint answerCount)
    {
        return(questions[questionKey].answerList.length);
    }

    function getQuestionAnswerAtIndex(bytes32 questionKey, uint answerRow)
        public
        constant
        returns(bytes32 answerKey)
    {
        return(questions[questionKey].answerList[answerRow]);
    }

    // in Ethereum we cannot pass dynamically sized arrays
    // function voteForAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32[] answerKeys)
    function voteForAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey)
         returns (bool success)
    {
        // is the sender allowed to do this?
        if (voters[msg.sender].enabled == false) {
            throw;
        }
        // TODO: check for question existence;
        if (questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] == true) {
            throw;
        }

        questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;
        questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].voteCount += 1;
        VoterVotedFor(msg.sender, questionKey, answerKey);

        return true;
    }

    function addVoter(address _voter)
        onlyOwner
        returns (bool success)
    {
        voters[_voter] = Voter(true);
        VoterAdded(_voter, this.text());
        return true;
    }

    event VoterAdded(address _newVoter, bytes32 _questionKey);
    event VoterVotedFor(address _voter, bytes32 _questionKey, bytes32 _answerKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible to pass a dynamic length array in/out of a function. See over here for a similar question with before/after code. [Returning dyanamic array from function](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13666/returning-dyanamic-array-from-function/13670#13670)

The gist is we need to think in fixed sized chunks.

Hope it helps.

**Re: Your updated code.**

All in all, a pretty good interpretation of the approach I suggested.

Your code is compiling in Browser Solidity. There is a warning near line 177. You use `this.text()` where `text` would have the same meaning. Point is it does compile and it *should* deploy.

In the picture above, `gas 0` suggests a failure to compile.

I think you might find Browser Solidity a better tool for working out the contract itself. Much faster feedback. If something goes haywire in deployment, that's a separate issue.

Mist isn't my tool of choice for deploying contracts. What I can say is there should be a gas estimate (not 0) if the contract compiles (should). Also, possibility something like this glitch is in the way: [Unable to define greeterContract in the Greeter tutorial. Breaking change in Solidity 0.4.9!](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11912/unable-to-define-greetercontract-in-the-greeter-tutorial-breaking-change-in-sol)

Comment: Ok, i changed the code to the following `function voteForAnswer(bytes32 questionKey, bytes32 answerKey)
         returns (bool success)
    {
        if (voters[msg.sender].enabled == false) {
            throw;
        }        
        if (questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] == true) {
            throw;
        }
        questions[questionKey].alreadyVoted[msg.sender] = true;

        questions[questionKey].answers[answerKey].voteCount += 1;
        VoterVotedFor(msg.sender, questionKey, answerKey);

        return true;
    }` but i get still an error from Mist

Comment: Maybe put the whole contract in the question so we see the problem?

Comment: Your code compiled for me in (with one warning) in Remix (a.k.a. browser Solidity) solc 0.4.8 and 0.4.10. So, in theory error is different now. Gas:0 suggests compiler error.

Comment: i'm so sorry!!! i changed simply the pragma from ^0.4.0 to 0.4.8 and i'm happy => sorry to bother you with so stupid questions

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are looking for is [`bytes`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=bytes32#dynamically-sized-byte-array) - a dynamically-sized array of `byte` that [gets the same special treatment as `string`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html?highlight=bytes32#arrays) does.

For comparison, the code provided uses a dynamically-sized array of `bytes32` - that is, chunks of 32 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

lets consider i have function whose input parameter is

```
bytes32

bytes32[ ] // array of type bytes 32

uint8
```

which looks like:

```
 function abc(bytes32 id, bytes32[ ] name,uint8 version) returns(bool)
    {  
        //
     }
```

so now to provoke the function (using remix) you have to pass parameters which looks like:

```
"0x12",["0x1262","0x12","0x12"],8
```