# Returning array of bytes32 in solidity

Tags: solidity

How to return an array from a function in solidity. Function is given :

```
function getTrackDetailsNew(bytes32 _iswc) public constant returns(bytes32[] isrc) {  
    bytes32 s;
    for(uint8 i=0;i<count;i++) {
        s = track[isrcKeyArray[i]].iswc;
        if(s == _iswc) {  
            isrc[i] = isrcKeyArray[i];  
        }  
    }  
    return isrc;  
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what is the error you get?

Comment: The error I am getting is : call to Trackdata.getTrackDetailsNew errored: VM error: invalid opcode.
invalid opcode 
 The execution might have thrown.
 Debug the transaction to get more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked for me.

```
function getTrackDetailsByIswc(bytes32 _iswc) public constant returns(bytes32[]) {

    getCount(_iswc);
    bytes32[] memory isrc = new bytes32[](c);

    bytes32 tempiswc;
    uint count = KeyArray.length;
    uint j;

    for (uint8 i=0; i < count; i++) {
        tempiswc = track[KeyArray[i]].iswc;
        if (tempiswc == _iswc) {
            isrc[j] = KeyArray[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    return isrc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in you returning a dynamic array, which is not supported ([see here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13666/returning-dyanamic-array-from-function)).

One option would be to instead return a fixed size array e.g.

```
function getTrackDetailsNew(bytes32 _iswc) public constant returns(bytes32[10] isrc) {  
    ...
}
```

However, this is somewhat limiting as you are stuck with a fixed size array.

An alternative could be to keep the dynamic isrc array in a public state variable which could be queried after the function has been executed.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need this data returned off-chain (not in a contract to contract call) you could simply iterate through the entries of a public array.